Restoring a deleted package
Yesterday we deleted an Installed Package from MC, but it turns out we need it so I would like to restore it.
Does anyone know if that's possible?
Thank you in advance!
UPDATE: I contacted Salesforce Support and they were able to restore it.

Once an installed package is deleted from MC, it typically cannot be restored through the usual user interface or settings. However, Salesforce does have a Recycle Bin feature for Content Builder that allows you to restore recently deleted items. For installed packages, this feature might not apply.
If you need to restore a deleted installed package, I recommend reaching out to Salesforce Support directly. They may have the ability to assist with such requests on a case-by-case basis. Additionally, it's always a good practice to have a backup of your configuration and data for such scenarios.
For future reference, consider documenting the setup and configuration of your installed packages, so that if a similar situation arises, you can reinstall and reconfigure the package based on your records.
